# Flutter Project getting

Tags: android, flutter, macos, project, flutter-test

Launching lib/main.dart on Redmi 4 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Note: /Users/mac/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-11.2.4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/messaging/JobIntentService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/mac/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_share-2.0.0/android/src/main/java/com/example/fluttershare/FlutterSharePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
/Users/mac/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/permission_handler-6.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/permissionhandler/ServiceManager.java:152: warning: [deprecation] getDefaultAdapter() in BluetoothAdapter has been deprecated
final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
^
error: warnings found and -Werror specified
1 error
1 warning

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':permission_handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 39s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I am getting this issue on my project since 2 days, I have tried every solution provided in the google or stack overflow please help me out with this issue.

Comment: try with `flutter clean` and rebuilding the app

Answer (score 0):

type

```
flutter clean
```

on your integrated terminal , and build again.